# Two working decipher keys giving various, valid results for one ciphered message - is it possible?

Tags: encryption, keys

Let's assume following scenario:

There's a ciphered message. Two decipher keys (let's name them A and B) are known.

Message deciphered with key A gives valid result - normal text but with no secret information. Let it be a poem or other meaningless content.

The same message deciphered with key B gives the right output, the real secret message revealed.

Please tell me, is it possible (or well-known and existing method/algorithm), or just a work of fiction? I've read about it in some novel a long time ago and tried to figure it out on my own, but with no result. But I'm rather ignorant in terms of cryptography so I might just miss something obvious.

Thank you in advance for any help - just a simple name of ciphering method or link to Wikipedia or something will be enough. I don't even dare to ask for the full and detailed explanation.

Comment: The one of the simpler examples is one-time pad. Assume you have two texts, $X$ and $Y$. First pick a random key $A$ and compute ciphertext $C = X \oplus A$. Then derive key $B$ as $B = C \oplus Y$. So, $C \oplus B = Y$ and $C \oplus A = X$.

Answer (score 2):

This property can be achieved with a [One-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad).

> "In fact, it is possible to "decrypt" out of the ciphertext any message whatsoever with the same number of characters, simply by using a different key, and there is no information in the ciphertext that will allow Eve to choose among the various possible readings of the ciphertext."

This is nicely shown in this [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad#Attempt_at_cryptanalysis) from Wikipedia (section "Attempt at cryptanalysis").

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys very much for your help and explanations.

I've started to Google for more info about one-time pad technique and found another suitable solution called Denial Encryption. Well, two of the most interesting content is available here, at crypto.stackexchange.com.... unfortunately I didn't find them before - maybe I didn't specify the proper search query - please don't blame me :)

Here they are, in case somebody looks for similar problem in future:

[Deniable Encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43086/one-ciphertext-multiple-keys-multiple-messages) (*term corrected according to comment by Gordon Davisson)

[Something similar, that could be helpful too](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10183/is-there-an-encryption-decryption-algorithm-that-can-give-two-different-outputs/10184#10184)

Thank you again and have a nice day.

P.S. I'm fully satisfied with answers received, so this topic could be freely closed/archived - I don't know how to do it on my own.

Comment: Correction: it's "denia**ble** encryption". Web searches will work better with the correct spelling :-) And there's a tag for it here on crypto.se: [deniable-encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deniable-encryption).

Comment: Yes, you're right - my fault. Thanks for letting me know, I've corrected the error.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, as links go dead all the time. Please make the answer self-contained by quoting the relevant parts of the linked resources.